# Convert a list of lists to array type in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, mlxtend

I have a matrix like this and want to convert it to  array for processing. How to do it

```
[[25  3  0  1  0  2  1]
 [ 1 21  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  3 18  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1  0  0 35  2  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  4 27  2  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  1 27  0]
 [ 1  1  0  0  0  0 34]]
```

I understand that it should be of the form

```
[[25,  3,  0,  1,  0,  2,  1],
 [ 1, 21,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [ 0,  3, 18,  0,  0,  0,  0],
 [ 1,  0,  0, 35,  2,  0,  0],
 [ 0,  0,  0,  4, 27,  2,  0],
 [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1, 27,  0],
 [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0, 34]]
```

Usually what i am doing is convert my array to the above form manually and calling

```
class = np.array([[28,  3,  0,  0,  5,  2,  1],
 [ 6, 25 , 0,  2,  2,  8,  0],
 [ 0 , 1 ,51 , 0,  0,  0,  0],
 [ 5 , 2 , 0 ,25, 12,  2,  2],
 [ 1 , 0 , 0,  2, 40,  6,  0],
 [ 0 , 0 , 0  ,0,  1, 48,  0],
 [ 2 , 1,  0  ,0 , 1,  1, 51]])
```

Comment: Is this list stored in a variable as a string?

Comment: Where is the matrix from and which format is it? Its not a valid syntax if you would copy it into python.

Comment: @user567879 are you reading the matrix from file?

Comment: Your middle block with commas is a list of lists, and the final `np.array` converts it correctly.  The first block looks like the `str` display of an array, a multiline string (but without quotes).

Comment: @Marco Yes its is stored in a variable as a string

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what format you have when importing the matrix, here a solution for a string based matrix.

```
from ast import literal_eval

s = '''
[[25  3  0  1  0  2  1]
 [ 1 21  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  3 18  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1  0  0 35  2  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  4 27  2  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  1 27  0]
 [ 1  1  0  0  0  0 34]]
'''
s = s.replace(" [","[").replace("[ ","[")
s = ", ".join(s.split())
ast.literal_eval(s)

# Out[12]: 
# [[25, 3, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1],
#  [1, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [0, 3, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [1, 0, 0, 35, 2, 0, 0],
#  [0, 0, 0, 4, 27, 2, 0],
#  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 27, 0],
#  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 34]]
```

---

or in one line:

```
ast.literal_eval(", ".join(s.replace(" [","[").replace("[ ","[").split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the matrix is stored on a string and it will always be integers, you can do:

```py
import re
import numpy as np

my_list = """
[[25  3  0  1  0  2  1]
 [ 1 21  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  3 18  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1  0  0 35  2  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  4 27  2  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  1 27  0]
 [ 1  1  0  0  0  0 34]]
"""

rows = []

for line in filter(len, map(str.strip, my_list.split("\n"))):
    rows.append([ int(v) for v in re.findall(r"\b[0-9]+\b", line) ])

np_rows = np.array(rows)
```

In that case,

```py
>>> np_rows
array([[25,  3,  0,  1,  0,  2,  1],
       [ 1, 21,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  3, 18,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  0,  0, 35,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  4, 27,  2,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1, 27,  0],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0, 34]])
```